# Replicating tables SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server-2008, stored-procedures, synchronization, job-scheduling, replicate

I need to replicate 6 tables in SQL server 2008 every 30 mins. 
Any Idea how to implement it?

Environment will be the server

Thanks,
Ryl

Comment: Replicate to what? Where? Your question has no information in it that people can use to answer it properly.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Transactional replication and schedule it to run every 30 minutes.